Next.js server actions for endpoints which aren't invoked from the client side?
With Next.js 13/14 server actions where introduced, which makes some endpoint declarations in pages/api/ obsolete.
What I'm not sure about: many of my endpoints are there for callbacks, e.g. in the authorization code flow when our oidc-provider returns a redirect (with a code to be exchanged for a JWT) towards a callback enpoint, and I even have a situation where an api endpoint is invoked by another service in the cluster without any preceeding action in my Next.js app. How can I convert these callback/endpoint handlers to server actions (b/c I still need to define the url they need to serve somehow), or should I just leave them as they are, i.e. in the api folder in an (apart from that) empty pages/ directory?

I figure what I was looking for were Route Handlers.
